# Error fatal en el IDE Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Porfa necesito de su ayuda. En mi android studio me sale un ERROR FATAL.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y que muestra el LogCat?

Comment: Has probado a limpiar la caché del android studio? Cuando ocurre este problema suele ser como bien indica el index, a mi con limpiar la caché y reiniciar Android Studio me funcionó

Comment: Bienvenido..Marcos..., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**,  te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar que realizaste anteriormente a este detalle, saludos!